Получаю ошибку "Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/" когда пытаюсь запустить собственный сайт
Разрабатываю сайт по курсу в ютубе, и при попытке запуска возникает ошибка в браузере Chrome
Вот полная ошибка:
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

Я пробовал добавить "Run npm start in terminal" в launch.json, менять настройки браузера и интернета.
Вот полный HTML код
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="container">
      <span class="logo">logo</span>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</li>
          <li><a href="#">News</li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="hero container">
      <div class="hero--info">
        <h2>3D game Dev </h2>
        <h1>Work that we produce for our clients</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.</p>
        <button class="btn">Get more details</button>
      </div>
      <img src="img/joystick.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="container trending">
      <a href="#" class="see all">SEE ALL</a>
      <h3>Currently Trending Games</h3>
      
      <div class="games">
        <div class="block">
          <img src="/img/game 1.png" alt="">
          <span><img src="/img/fire.svg" alt="">40 Followers</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <img src="/img/game 2.png" alt="">
          <span><img src="/img/fire.svg" alt="">40 Followers</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <img src="/img/game 3.png" alt="">
          <span><img src="/img/fire.svg" alt="">40 Followers</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
          <img src="/img/game 4.png" alt="">
          <span><img src="/img/fire.svg" alt="">40 Followers</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container big-text">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container banner">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
      <img src="/img/banner.png" alt="">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="features">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature1.png" alt="">
            <p>Mobile Game Development</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature2.png" alt="">
            <p>PC Game Development</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature3.png" alt="">
            <p>PS4 Game Development</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature4.png" alt="">
            <p>AR/VR Solutions</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature5.png" alt="">
            <p>AR/ VR design</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <img src="img/feature6.png" alt="">
            <p>3D Modelings</p>
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container projects">
        <h3>Our Recent Projects</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <div class="images">
          <img src="img/Project1.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/Project2.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/Project3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="images">
          <img src="img/Project4.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/Project5.png" alt="">
          <img src="img/Project6.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <a href="" class="see-all">SEE ALL</a>
      </div>

      <div class="container email">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        <div class="block">
          <div>
            <h4>Stay in the loop</h4>
            <p>Subscribe to receive the latest news and updates about TDA.
We promise not to spam you! </p>
            <div>
              <input type="email" id="#emailField" placeholder="Enter email address">
              <button onclick="checkEmail()">Continue</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      


    </div>
    
  <footer>
    <div class="blocks container">
      <div>
        <span class="logo">logo</span>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>About us</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Zeus</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Careers</li>
          <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Contact us</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        <p>+908 89097 890</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <p>Copyright ® 2021 Lorem All rights Received</p>
  </footer>

      <script>
        function checkEmail(){
          let email = document.querySelector('#emailField').value;
          if(!email.includes('@')) alert('Нет символа @')
          else if(!email.includes('.')) alert('Нет символа .')
          else alert('Все отлично!')
      }
      </script>
</body>
</html>

Вот CSS
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700;800&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(74, 40, 0, 1) 100%
    );
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

header.logo,
footer .blocks .logo {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li.active::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #dc7000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: -15px;
}

header nav ul li:not(.active):not(.btn) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dc7000;
}

header nav ul li.btn a,
.email .block button {
    background: #fa9021;
    padding: 9px 17px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

header nav ul li.btn a:hover,
.email .block button:hover {
    background: #a02604;
}

.hero {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero--info {
    width: 530px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.hero--info h2 {
    color: #e87d0e;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.hero--info h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.hero--info p {
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 170%;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.hero--info .btn {
    background: #fa9021;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.hero--info .btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hero img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    right: 0;
}

/* Секция с играми */
.trending {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.trending h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 31px;
}

.trending .see-all,
.projects .see-all {
    color: #fff;
    background: #25211d;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 12px 23px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.trending .see-all:hover,
.projects .see-all:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.trending .games {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.trending .games span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.trending .games span img {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.big-text {
    padding: 50px 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}

.banner {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.banner h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.banner p {
    line-height: 170%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 550px;
}

.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Секция с изображениями */

.features {
    background: url('/img/BG.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.features h3,
.features p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.features h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.features .info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.features .info .block {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 30px 2%;
}

.features .info .block img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.projects {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.projects h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.projects p {
    margin: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.projects .images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.projects .see-all {
    float: none;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Нижняя часть */

.email {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.email h3 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.email .block {
    background: #1c140f;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px 3%;
    width: 94%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.email .block h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.email .block h4 {
    width: 500px;
}

.email .block input {
    background: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 380px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: -95px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-right: 120px;
}

.email .block input::placeholder {
    color: #898989;
}

.email .block button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 13px 17px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 50px;
}

footer .blocks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .blocks p {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

footer .blocks h4 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
}

footer .blocks .ul {
    list-style: none;
}

footer .blocks .ul .li {
    margin-top: 7px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

footer .hr {
    margin: 30px 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 0.6px;
    background: #ccc;
}

footer > p {
    text-align: center;
}

